# is it possible to have level metering in AVQueuePlayer on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audiotoolbox, avqueueplayer

Using AVAudioPlayer I can get the volume in RMS or peak by calling peakPowerForChannel;
unluckly I have an implementation using AVQueuePlayer, because the app need to continue playing in background.

is it possible to have level metering in AVQueuePlayer on iOS?
Should I switch to AVAudioPlayer? in this case, how to avoid the app stopping playing when backgrounded?